# how can I customize a the tick using tickFormatter in PolarAngleAxis for RadarChart?

Tags: recharts

I want the radarchart to display the labels with customized font styles and oriention (in terms of rotation).
Basically I want to decrease the font size and rotate the text, can some body give me an example of tickFormmater in PolarAngleAxis.
`

`

Answer (score 2):

To format label you can use `tick={{ fontSize: 11 }}` in

```
<PolarAngleAxis tick={{ fontSize: 11 }} >
```

Comment: It looks like your answer got cut off.

Comment: @EllenSpertus The reason being, as usual, unformatted code containing angle brackets.

Answer (score -5):

Try this code option

```
<YAxis tickFormatter={this.customTickFormatter}/>

customTickFormatter(e){
//e holds the actual value
    return (<div className="custom-tick">
             e
            </div>)
  }
```

Use `.custom-tick` for to apply font, rotation css.